# Simple Conditional Formatting Rule Not Working in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I found other Excel conditional formatting questions on the board but couldn't find a solution for mine.

The rule is simple: if cell B10 equals "y", then format (I'm formatting B12)...

**B10="y"**  This is what I enter into the rule field before closing the box... The cell (B12) still won't format...

Additionally, when I re-open the conditional formatting window, I find that extra quotes have been added... Aside from that, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Lose the quotation mark in front of `B10`.

Answer (score 1):

There is additional quotation mark:

[image: I marked it on a screen dump]

Consider formatting based on cell content instead of using formula:
[image: see on a picture] :)

Comment: @majesticoj, can I ask you to accept the answer? [Here is why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :) Thanks!